# Search icon is not visible in search box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, search-box

I want to have a clickable search icon inside the search box but the icon is not visible in the search box.The class icon-search does not seem to be working.I used bar instead of navbar for customizing its height and its working fine.Plus,how should I customize the height of the search box?

```
<div  class="bar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
            <span id="logo">  
                <a href="main.php">XYZ</a>
            </span>
            <span class="col-xs-5 right-inner-addon ">
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</span>
    </div>   
</div>

.right-inner-addon {
    padding-top: 6px;
    position: relative;
}
.right-inner-addon input {
    padding-right: 30px;    
}
.right-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 10px 6px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.bar{
    min-width: 800px;
    background-color: #563d7c;  
    width:100%; 
    height:43px;    
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px #888888;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap 3 you can try using the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5888/

```
<div  class="bar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <span id="logo">  
            <a href="main.php">XYZ</a>
        </span>
        <span class="col-xs-5 right-inner-addon ">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Test" />
                <span class="input-group-addon" for="search">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: thanks..it works fine but the search icon is in button form..how can i  can I make the icon to be clickable

Comment: I updated my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5890/ It now works on search click. If this answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: when I click on the form the search icon is like a separate button.. I want that when I click on the form, it should be inside the form(like in fb search bar).Plus, can you provide some brief idea on how to customize the height(height across which it stretches,that is,its vertical width) of search box.

Comment: You could try creating a search icon png file and then setting the background of the search input to that png file